# Context: Used as a part in this library. : Error: 'Workbook' isn't a type

Tags: flutter

I am using syncfusion_flutter_xlsio-18.4.49-beta to generate excel ,
The project about 5 Months old ,
and I try to run now , but I am getting this issue ,

```
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
/C:/src/flutter/flutter_1.22.4/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_xlsio-18.4.49-beta/lib/xlsio.dart%20: Context: Used as a part in this library.
/C:/src/flutter/flutter_1.22.4/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_xlsio-18.4.49-beta/lib/xlsio.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
/C:/src/flutter/flutter_1.22.4/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_xlsio-18.4.49-beta/lib/src/xlsio/security/security_helper.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
/C:/src/flutter/flutter_1.22.4/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_xlsio-18.4.49-beta/lib/xlsio.dart%20: Context: Used as a part in this library.
/C:/src/flutter/flutter_1.22.4/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_xlsio-18.4.49-beta/lib/xlsio.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
: Error: 'Workbook' isn't a type.
    final Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
          ^^^^^^^^
: Error: Method not found: 'Workbook'.
final Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
                              ^^^^^^^^
```

I upgarde my project to flutter 2.5.0 but still this error . please help me

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by upgrading flutter version...